# Link com popup de video youtube

Tags: link, popup

Eu preciso criar um link em uma imagem onde qdo clicar na imagem abre um popup centralizado na tela com o video do youtube, esta funcionando mas o que eu fiz não sei se seria o correto, alguém pode me ajudar?

Link=>

```
<a <label onclick="PopupCenter('https://www.youtube.com/embed/INQcOCgpOXs','785','680')"
                             style="cursor:pointer;"></label>
                    <img style="margin-right: -4.5px; border:solid 1px #ffffff" class="espaco"  src="imagens/thumb/atomizador_250lts_25_thumb.png" alt="" />
                    </a>
```

Script do popup =>

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
        var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
        var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
        var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=650px' + w + ', height=450px' + h + ', top=100%' + ', left=' + left);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: A sintaxe do seu link está confusa. Pode revisar? Há um elemento `label` sendo definido dentro de um `a`.

Comment: Sim, não conheço muito ainda, segui algumas explicações no google e fiz assim, esta funcionando mas não sei se é o correto pra se fazer.

Comment: Sim eu criei novamente, pois essa pergunta aqui ninguem me respondia, parece as pessoas só querem dar o primeiro comentário e depois não se importam mais com a pergunta. Temos que ter sorte pra o primeiro que responder resolver pq depois ninguem mais comenta. Por isso tive que criar outra pergunta, porque esse Anderson Carlos que respondeu, somente quis responder e ajudou em nada, e ninguem mais comentou pra me ajudar. Ai criei outra pergunta e lá me ajudaram a resolver.